# I want to add delay before each click

Tags: javascript

I want to click all same class button of a webpage. And i want to add delay before each click. Can anyone please help me to achieve that?

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-info btn-xs');
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)  
setTimeout(buttons[i].click(), 3000)
```

Comment: you missed curly brackets for the loop

Comment: Have you considered using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to stagger clicking elements in script? More information about their usage can be looked up on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: I tried like this but not working.



var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-info btn-xs');
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)  
setTimeout(buttons[i].click(), 3000)

Comment: Check out `setTimeout` and `setInterval` it will help over here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: I'm unable to do that. Can anyone please help me to done this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `setTimeout` API. and make sure loop variable `i` is declared as `let`.

Button 1 will clicked instantly, then each click will wait 2 seconds.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonClass');
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // button[i].click();
    console.log(buttons[i].textContent)
  }, i * 2000);
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonClass" >Button 1</button>
<button class="buttonClass" >Button 2</button>
<button class="buttonClass" >Button 3</button>
<button class="buttonClass" >Button 4</button>
<button class="buttonClass" >Button 5</button>
<button class="buttonClass" >Button 6</button>
<button class="buttonClass" >Button 7</button>
<button class="buttonClass" >Button 8</button>
```

Comment: Not working. It's clicking all the link after 1 second not each link after 1 second

Comment: Okok, understood. so first button should be clicked after 1 second, then 2nd button should be clicked after 2 seconds, something like this?

Comment: Button1 Clicked
[Waited 2 Second]
Button2 Clicked
[Waited 2 Second]
Button3 Clicked

Comment: okok, updating answer. please wait a minute

Comment: Yes Sure Please.

Comment: Hi, updated the answer. please try and check if it solves your problem

Comment: Another problem appear. It's checking >> Button-1 Clicked [Waited 2 Seconds] Button-3 Clicked [Waited 2 Seconds] Button-5 Clicked [Waited 2 Seconds].... It's not clicking all the buttons. It's clicking one then skipping 2nd then clicking 3rd skipping 4th.

Comment: Added the snippets, You can run and see in logs that it's not skipping any buttons